# How can I call multiple function at the same time using swift

Tags: swift

Hello everyone I have a question about swift. I need to call multiple function, let say function one, function two and function three; How can I create a function to call those three function or method at the same time?

Comment: What do you mean by "at the same time"?

Answer (score 0):

If by 'at the same time' you mean to run async, it's pretty simple. You'd just need to call Grand Central Dispatch to make each function run on a different thread.

Look at the Swift docs for more help on the GCD.

Answer (score -1):

Paste the following in a playground:

```
import Foundation

func method1() -> String {

    return "method1"
}

func method2() -> String {

    return "method2"
}

func method3() -> String {

    return "method3"
}


func callThreeFunctions () {
    println(method1())
    println(method1())
    println(method1())
}


callThreeFunctions()
```

This is one way.  There are others.  If you were thinking of something else, let me know what you are looking for.

Comment: can you tell how to call concurrently  function using thread or nsoperationqueue